# Typescript function overloading: typescript does not analyze function code

Tags: typescript, overloading

Consider following function overloading and implementation with bugs.

```js
function foo(param: number): boolean;
function foo(param: string): string;

function foo(param) {
  if (typeof param === "number") {
    // typescript does not complain that 12 is not boolean
    return 12;
  } else if (typeof param === "string") {
    // typescript does not complain that {} is not string
    return {};
  }
}
```

Here is how one can interpret it:

1. if function `foo` takes numeric param it should return boolean
2. if function `foo` takes string param it should return string
3. another calls should be prohibited

Sure it is possible for type checker to verify 1&2 by analyzing function code.
But typescript does not do this - it only does 3.

Is it possible to achieve in typescript above mentioned behavior?

Comment: See the discussion on this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13225. TL;DR: Function overload in TypeScript is simply a coverage check, and does not actually attempt to validate the return types.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `function foo(param)`. This adds a third overload with `param` typed as `any`.

```
function foo(param: number): boolean;
function foo(param: string): string {
  if (typeof param === "number") {
    return 12;
  } else if (typeof param === "string") {
    return {};
  }
}
```

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&declaration=false&ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAHAhgJywWwC5EwR8AjAUxwEpjzUAbSrMAbgChRJYFlVMuAsQDOUHDDABzOojETpiAN4dEiGMERooATwyU4m7HnyIAvBcQAiUhWpWay1WsQ5KUEDiQBGAEyc1AF9ESkYRSnVNbT0DIyFTCzNreUkpBycXV3dPJCVAgMRAjkCgA)